# Как на java из БД SQLite достать нужные данные?

Tags: android, java, sqlite

Меня интересует, как можно получить курсор из БД с данными, где какое-нибудь конкретное поле было с нужной последовательностью символов, а другие поля с разными.

Пример: У меня есть БД с полями  ИМЯ, ФАМИЛИЯ, ОТЧЕСТВО.   Я буду искать данные по ИМЯ. Мне нужно вывести всех, у кого имя либо начинается на "А" или всех,у кого имя Александр, думаю, вы поняли,что меня интересует. Какого характера должен быть запрос query()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select ИМЯ, ФАМИЛИЯ, ОТЧЕСТВО from МОЯ_ТАБЛИЦА where ИМЯ like 'A%'
```

русские имена лучше сразу заменить на английские аналоги во избежание различных странных багов (я надеюсь в таблице оно все латиницей записано?)

Comment: Одно небольшое уточнение: SQLite не умеет искать русские символы в режиме case-insensitive, только с учетом регистра.

Comment: К сожалению они записаны на русском и аналогами их заменить никак нельзя. Спасибо за ответ, плюсанул

Comment: Кстати, Бармалей. Вы в прошлых постах про доступ к БД ответили,что лучше использовать ContentProvider,я так и сделал и это куда лучше,чем прямые обращения к БД, он всё делает за меня и никаких ошибок,вы очень мне помогли

Comment: Во избежание надо запрос модифицировать так:

`select ИМЯ, ФАМИЛИЯ, ОТЧЕСТВО from МОЯ_ТАБЛИЦА where ИМЯ like 'A%  or ИМЯ like 'a%'`